how to make the cursor last when writing css style enters
When VS Code writes CSS styles, the cursor is always in '; ' front, every time you need to manually press the right arrow key, and then press the enter key to wrap the line, very troublesome, is there any way to write the cursor according to the automatic prompt and then last

I hope that after selecting a color value, the cursor will be at the end of the line, so that I can directly press Enter to change the line and continue writing.

You can press Ctrl+Enter to go straight to a new line below. This runs the command Insert Line Below editor.action.insertLineAfter. I assume the equivalent on MacOS is Cmd+Enter.
